# Effective estimation for sums of Fourier coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ be a bounded exceptionally well behave function and let the sequence $\{a_n\}\in\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}$ be the Fourier coefficients for $h$. My goal is to effectively bound the sum $$A(h)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|a_n|$$

Specifically as $h$ approaches the indicator function of an interval I want to bound how this blows up. Let $\mathcal{S}_{n,p}(h) = ||h^{(n)}||_p$ where $h^{(n)}$ is $n$th derivative of $h$ and $||\cdot||_p$ is the normal $L^p$ norm ($1\leq p\leq\infty$). One can somewhat easily show that $A(h)\ll\mathcal{S}_{2,2}(h)$ by the Fourier expansion of $h^{(2)}$ which is simply $\{-n^2a_n\}$. We then have very crudely $$|a_nn^2|\leq(\sum_n|n^4a_n^2|)^{1/2}=\mathcal{S}_{2,2}(h)$$ so $a_n\leq \mathcal{S}_{2,2}(h)/n^2$. However I suspect a better bound would be something like $\mathcal{S}_{1,\infty}(h)$ but this doesn't seem so easy to show.

I suppose that in general how various norms on the sequence $\{a_n\}$ translate into (or are bounded by) Sobolev norms on $h$ is very well understood but this doesn't seem to be mentioned in any of the resources I have looked at.

Comment: Dealing with $\mathcal{S}_{n,p}(h)$ for $p\neq 2$ is never as simple as the $p=2$ case (which is almost trivial a lot of the time thanks to Plancherel's theorem). For this, typically what one wants is some sort of Littlewood-Paley theory (which recovers to some extent the info from the FT/FS side by looking at averages at all scales of localized frequency patches). Are you familiar with L-P theory? If not I recommend L. Grafakos's books on Fourier Analysis.

Comment: No I am not very familiar with L-P theory. I will check out the book you mention, though from the rest of your comment I am guessing there is not a simple answer to this question. Thank you for the information!

Comment: You also might want to take a look at Katznelson's "An introduction to harmonic analysis", it has a whole section devoted to functions with absolutely convergent fourier series.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it.